# How to disable row limit permanently in pentaho dev console?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Is there any option for disable the row limit permanently in pentaho console. [Temporarly we can uncheck the row limit from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFXrR.png)

Is any option in BA server to disable(uncheck) the row limit??
please help..

Answer (score 0):

Row limit is a feature of interactive reporting. Interactive reporting is a plugin for pentaho platform and available for ee distribution. All settings for this plugin including default row limit is in this plugin folder. Row limit is quite unstable in pre-7 pentaho versions and you can always disable it in

```
\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\pentaho-interactive-reporting\settings.xml
```

having...

```
<!--
     The maximum number of results to be loaded for the Filter search list for any
     given search string.
  -->
<search-list-limit>-1</search-list-limit>
```

By default it is set to 500 and that is why your have limit 500 by default. Also you may find other useful options there...